# What is the probability at least one bulb is burnt out after time t?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given three lightbulbs whose lifetimes $X_i$ are exponential random variables with parameters $\lambda_i = i$, for $i = 1, 2, 3$ respectively. If all bulbs are switched on at time '0' what is the P(at least one bulb is burnt out at time t)?

It has been a while since I have studies probability and I am very rusty. So, as far as I know, we are looking for $P(X_1 \leq 1) \cup P(X_2 \leq 1) \cup P(X_3 \leq 1)$. Is this then the sum of $P(X_1 \leq 1) + P(X_2 \leq 1) + P(X_3 \leq 1) = (1 - e^{\lambda_{1}t}) + (1 - e^{\lambda_{2}t}) + (1 - e^{\lambda_{3}t})$ or am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Better to consider the case that all *three*
 are still burning at time t. This is easier to compute and from this you get the other probability immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some misplaced parenthesis, and so your first calculation doesn't make sense.

Anyway, it might be easier to calculate the complementary probability, i.e. P(None of the bulbs are burnt out after time t)=$P(X_1 \geq t )P(X_2 \geq t )P(X_3 \geq t )$.

Now $P(X_1 \geq t )= 1-P(X_1 \leq t)=1-F(t)$ where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function.